# Scrolled content ignoring CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I ensure, that in this example:

```css
.wrapper{
  width:300px;
  overflow:auto;
}

.content{
  background: red;
  width:100%
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="content">
  adsfkasdöfjkalsdjkaölsdfasödfjasdölfkajsdklöfajsdkflöasdfajsdfasdöadjf   öklasdakdslfjasdölkfjasdlökfjasdkfajdsflköadsaklödsjaslköfjadslköjasdölfjasdklfj
  </div>
</div>
```

when I scroll to the right, the text also still has a red background. It seems that CSS is taking the width of the displayed content to apply the background color, not the whole scrollable content.

Comment: `.content {...,  width: -webkit-fit-content}`

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `.content` takes 100% width of its parent `.wrapper`, which is 300px. Remove it.

Setting `.content` to `display: inline-block` does the trick:

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 300px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.content {
  display: inline-block;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="content">    adsfkasdöfjkalsdjkaölsdfasödfjasdölfkajsdklöfajsdkflöasdfajsdfasdöadjf öklasdakdslfjasdölkfjasdlökfjasdkfajdsflköadsaklödsjaslköfjadslköjasdölfjasdklfj
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just apply the background to the wrapper instead of the content:

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 300px;
  overflow: auto;
  background: red;
}

.content {
  width: 100%
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="content">
    adsfkasdöfjkalsdjkaölsdfasödfjasdölfkajsdklöfajsdkflöasdfajsdfasdöadjf öklasdakdslfjasdölkfjasdlökfjasdkfajdsflköadsaklödsjaslköfjadslköjasdölfjasdklfj
  </div>
</div>
```